# When are solutions of nonlinear ODE bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder if there is a method other than solving to find out whether the solutions of a specific differential equations are bounded? I am interested in equations of the form
$$
\frac{dx_i(t)}{dt} = \sum_j A_{ij}x_j + \sum_{jk}B_{ijk}x_jx_k \\
\text{ with } B_{ijk} = 0 \text{ if any index coincides.}
$$
e.g. only equations with linear terms in the same index and linear combinations.

Comment: exactly, bounded.

Comment: Then the answer is no. For example $x'=x$ or $x'=x^2$ destroys any hope.

Comment: Well, these are the cases when its not bounded, but its easy to see.

Comment: ? It seems that in dimension $1$ the equation is simply $x'=ax+bx^2$. So, what is then your question?

Comment: We certainly know when the bernoulli equation is bounded. What about the others?